# HTTP connector for Geneva actions fails with "Bearer error=\"invalid_token\", error_description=\"The signature is invalid\""

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am using Azure AD for authentication in my Geneva workflow, the code snippet is pasted below

```
{
    "inputs": {
        "method": "POST",
        "uri": "https://debugbot.trafficmanager.net/DebugBareMetal?scenarioType=anyToAny&srcResourceUri=/subscriptions/01d55b53-0203-4c60-8849-205598b4078b/resourceGroups/np-g-5726727a-f2ae-482f-92a5-abb03eeb0fc4/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/c-np-dfae3b00&destResourceUri=/subscriptions/01d55b53-0203-4c60-8849-205598b4078b/resourceGroups/SDNAPPLIANCEINSIGHTS-GLOBAL-RESOURCES-EASTUS2EUAP/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/BN7-AZB-DR244-NA002_VNIC&cloudType=public&allowHistorical=false&durationInMinutes=0",
        "authentication": {
            "type": "ActiveDirectoryOAuth",
            "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
            "tenant": "33e01921-4d64-4f8c-a055-5bdaffd5e33d",
            "audience": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
            "clientId": "5b4f7b22-68b8-4f82-a5ad-b15d83303e9a",
            "secret": "@{parameters('HTTPAuthAppSecret')}"
        }
    }
}
```

The AAD App is multi-tenant and has been allow-listed by the service url. Am i missing something to make this POST call? DO I need to setup my AAD app to expose an API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The settings  Audience and Authority are must and should be in
   proper format. Authority must be something like
   `"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId`

   ***The Authority value is the concatenation of the Instance and TenantId values.***

   ```
   "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
   "TenantId": "[Enter the tenantId here]",
   ```

   So please make sure to either give `instance and tenant` **or** only
   `authority` itself completely.
2. And scope=openid profile email User.Read are required if you are
   calling Microsoft graph :[azure-ad-troubleshooting](https://authguidance.com/azure-ad-troubleshooting/)

   If the app is not calling graph ,scope must be something like `scope : {api app client_id}/.default`

or other required scope like
`https://api/<appId >/user_impersonation` or `Application (client) ID/.default`

in this case the audience must be the appId or appidUri of the application.

***References:***

1. [azure issues .github](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-spring-boot/issues/476#issuecomment-625770119)
2. [AzureAD.github](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/609#issuecomment-555401555)

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you. Other higher priorities prevented me from trying the recommended recipe. First, to respond to your suggestion I did find a app specific scope to use in my HTTP post call. The scope was only available in MS tenant, but devops needs an AME account so I created a keyvault in AME and added the secret to my MS App.

Comment: {
    "uri": "https://debugbot.trafficmanager.net/DebugBareMetal?scenarioType=anyToAny&srcResourceUri=",
    "method": "POST",
    "authentication": {
        "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47",
        "tenant": "72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47",
        "audience": "https://microsoft.onmicrosoft.com/DebugBot.Api/user_impersonation",
        "clientId": "9a9824ea-9480-4c64-afe9-44b3d208a5a5",
        "secret": "*sanitized*",
        "type": "ActiveDirectoryOAuth"
    }
}

Comment: However I am getting the error message, BadGateway. Http request failed as there is an error getting AD OAuth token: 'Failed to extract error details from response content ''.'.